# English statements to first order logic?

Tags: first-order-logic

[image]

I kind of understand what I need to do. However, it is the exact syntax that I am struggling with.

For the first answer,

$$C = \{ (a,x)|a,x \in M \land a \text{ is a child of } x \} \land W/L = \{x \in W \land x \notin L\}$$

I feel like I am on the right track, just whatever I am doing needs to be cleaned up a bit.

Thanks,

Comment: Can I ask what's the book?

Comment: The suggested book for the course is A Concise Introduction to Mathematical Logic by Wolfgang Rautenberg

Answer (score 1):

For the first answer, I'd write

$$\forall x,(C(a,x)\land W(x)) \implies \lnot L(x).$$

(read: if $x$ is the female parent of $a$, $x$ is not alive)

Comment: You need to quantify $x$.  Also, $C$ is a binary predicate; hence you write $C(a,x)$ instead of $(a,x) \in C$.  Likewise for $W$ and $L$.

Comment: You need to bring back the implication instead of the comma.

Comment: Yes, it's OK now.